# How to get all registered Vuex modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuex-modules

Is there any way to iterate over all Vuex modules?  I registered my namespaced modules like this:

```js
$store.registerModule('module-xyz', module);
```

Now is there any way to get the list of all of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's undocumented, but you can get all modules through the `_modules` property:

```js
console.log(this.$store._modules.root._children);
```

You can also check for the existence of a module with [`hasModule`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#hasmodule):

```js
console.log(this.$store.hasModule('module-xyz'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your store modules are namespaced, the module names will be available in your store state as properties. So, you could check those properties against `$store.hasModule()` to get a list of all the modules.

Example:

```js
Object.keys(this.$store.state).filter((stateKey) => this.$store.hasModule(stateKey))
// ['moduleA', 'moduleB']
```

If you have nested modules and need to represent the structure of the nesting, you could could recursively loop over the nested state as you check for modules.

Example of getting all modules (including nested):

```js
function getStoreModules(store, state = store.state, parentModules = []) {
    return Object.keys(state)
        .filter((stateKey) => store.hasModule([...parentModules, stateKey]))
        .flatMap((moduleName) => {
            const modulePath = [...parentModules, moduleName];
            return [modulePath.join('/'), ...getStoreModules(store, state[moduleName], modulePath)];
        });
}
getStoreModules(this.$store);
// ['moduleA', 'moduleA/nestedModuleA', 'moduleB']
```